# Using Density Histogram on FindCluster

Tags: plotting, cluster-analysis

I have some data which I want to put in a `DensityHistogram` after i have clustered
it. The different clusters should have different colors and based on how many are in one bin the color should have a different strength. I have no idea how to do this so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[1]
data = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {10^4, 2}];
n = 3;
clusters = FindClusters[data, n];
lengths = Length /@ clusters;
ranks = Ordering@Ordering[- lengths];
colors = {Red, Green, Blue}[[ranks]];
legends = SwatchLegend[colors, 
     "cluster " <> ToString[#] <> " : length = " <> ToString[lengths[[#]]] & /@ Range[n]];

Legended[Show[
  DensityHistogram[#, ColorFunction -> Function[{h}, Opacity[h, #2 ]]] & @@@ 
   Transpose[{clusters, colors}], PlotRange -> All], legends]
```

[image]

Use `n=5` and `colors = {Red, Green, Blue, Orange, Magenta}[[ranks]]` to get:

[image]

Use the same bin width for each cluster (`{.1}`) to get

[image]